# How to diagnose why the package appears to be invalid?

Tags: android

I have been coding my Android app, making minor changes. I compile it on Windows (10), Archive it and then copy it to my attached Android. All going OK, until I get "package appears invalid". How do I diagnose what is invalid and how to fix it? I commented out the latest code, but still get this error.

I compile (VS 2022) with minimum level of 32 and target of 33.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer. Just as mysteriously as this "error" appeared, now it's gone. Not doing anything differently that I know of.

Comment: Welcome to Hybrid Android Development!